# Math.random() with do while loop sometimes hang the page

Tags: javascript, random, while-loop

I am making a simple game where I need to generate an object

1. its position x and y needs to be in certain range.
2. it must not overlap with some existing objects.

I use the `Math.random()` and the `do while` loop for that, but the game intermittently crashes.

I cannot see any flaw in the logic, but why it crashes?

```js
 let posX, posY;
 let invalid = false;
     do {
         posX = getRandomInt(0,100);
         posY = getRandomInt(0,100);
         if (posX > 20 &&
             posX < 40 &&
             posY > 20 &&
             posY < 40
            )
              invalid = true;
        }
        while (invalid)
 alert("not crash!")
 function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

Comment: What the crash/exception description?

Comment: It hangs because it cannot find a suitable number and therefore loops a lot of times.

Comment: You set `invalid` to `true`, but then never reset it to `false` when the values are OK. So if the values are not OK the first time in the loop, you will loop forever. Solution: put `invalid = false` inside the loop.